# compiler execution sequence

Tags: c, compilation, microcontroller

I am programming a microcontroller in C language and I’ve faced the following situation: To enable/disable the internal clock generator, I need to first write a protection key to a specific register and after make the enable/disable operation, writing in another register.
The user manual specify the following about this operation:
[snip from user manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1cE0.png)

As you can see in the highlighted part of the text, the piece of code that make this two operation (writing protection key and enable the oscillator) is very sensitive, because any operation should be executed between this two register access. Therefore, I start to concern about any situation that could led to a non sequential execution of this two operations.
I know that it is common to temporary disable interruption while executing sensitive piece of codes, but I was wonder if there is any compiler optimization that could insert another operation between this two register access. So, in C programming, there is any compiler directive to ensure that it will not happen?

Actually, I even do not know if make sense to think that the compiler will mix the sequence of instructions written in C language. I remember to have already heard that it could happens sometimes, in the speed optimization process. If I am wrong, sorry about and thanks in advance for the clarification.

Comment: You probably need the `volatile` keyword-

Comment: Indeed, accesses to `volatile` can't be reordered. But the compiler is still free to order non-volatile accesses at will, which AFAIR includes *between* two volatile accesses. Therefore, I'd opt for coding this sequence as an assembler snippet and inline it in the C code (e.g. `__asm__ volatile(" ... ")`)

Comment: If this is a common thing to do on your target platform, it's quite possible that the runtime library already has a function available, so you don't need to write the assembly yourself.

Comment: The pointers for this registers are already volatile.

However, I understood that I should declare the function which operates the register as volatile or use assembly commands with volatile keyword, as @FelixPalmen pointed.

Is this right?

Comment: @LuisPossatti when it comes to inline assembly, there's nothing at all in the standard. With `gcc`, `volatile` on an assembly block forces the compiler to include the assembly fragment, even if it doesn't have any influence on the observable behavior of the C program -- otherwise, the optimizer could decide this code isn't needed :)

Comment: I think now I got the trick, @FelixPalmen. So if I want to ensure two register writes to happen in sequence, with anything else in the middle, I should write a volatile inline assembly with both writes operations.

Thanks

Comment: @LuisPossatti if your function only has `volatile` accesses, this should be safe as well. But I'd say inline assembly is the safest choice...

Comment: neither volatile nor bit banding will cover this topic.  There isnt anything in the C language that will insure that separate register accesses will be in order without others in the middle.  If you want specific accesses in a specific order you have to control the machine code which is best done in assembly language (that or write the machine code directly).   You are very likely to get lucky, but dont confuse luck with a reliable solution, no reason to assume that a re-build of the code in the future or code changes will still work.

Comment: you also have to wrap these accesses with code to disable interrupts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of toggling bits in C involves a read-modify-write sequence of instructions.
Some unwanted operations may happen between those instructions and the usual approach is to either disable the interrupts or to use bit-banding.

What bit-banding is, it allows to you toggle bits using one instruction(without going into details how it happens).

If your microcontroller allows you to use bit-banding, then that should fix all your problems.

If you can't use bit-banding, then you have to sit and think what interrupts may cause problems to you and temporarily disable them.

To get back to the core of the question - you must declare all of your registers volatile for two main reasons:

1. Unlike ordinary memory that is only modified by the program itself, the value stored in those memory mapped registers can change at any time, what the compiler will do is just optimize away all reads and writes to the register. Volatile prevents this.By declaring a variable volatile, you're effectively asking the compiler to be as inefficient as possible when it comes to reading or writing that variable. Specifically, the compiler should generate code to perform each and every read from a volatile variable as well as each and every write to a volatile variable even if you write it twice in a row or read it and ignore the result. Not a single read or write can be skipped. In other words, no compiler optimizations are allowed with respect to volatile variables.
2. In a nutshell, the order of accesses of volatile variables A and B in the object code must be the same as the order of those accesses in the source code. The compiler is not allowed to reorder volatile variable accesses for any reason. (Consider what might go wrong if the referenced memory locations were hardware registers like in this case). Volatile guarantees you that everything happens in the sequence you specify in your code and no reorderings are being made.

To sum it up - use bit-banding and declare the registers volatile.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the bit-banding stuffs, I will check it out.
However, I was asking about problemas others than unexpected interruptions, specially instructions execution order after compilation.

Comment: Edited the answer to be more specific

Comment: Now it is well better. Thanks for the correction. Won't upvote because dont have enough reputation yet :(